# Alert when input range change to specific value

Tags: jquery, html

I trying to receive an alert when sliding an input type range to the his last value (100) with the following code and is not working:

```
<input id="now" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider">

<script>
    $(document).on('input', '#now', function() {
        $( "#now" ).mouseup(function() {
            if ($('#now').attr('value') = 100 ) {
                alert('Now!');
            }            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong. Can someone please give me some light. Thanks.

Comment: `if ($('#next').attr('value') = 100 )` should be `if ($('#next').attr('value') == 100 )` **or**  `if ($('#next').attr('value') === 100 )`

Comment: Nop. Still not working :(

Comment: `$('#now').attr('value') = 100` -> assigning value `$('#now').attr('value') == 100` | `$('#now').attr('value') === 100` -> comparing value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `mouseup` first of all .. and you don't need to be looking for `attr()` you need to be looking for `val()`    --  Value isn't an `attribute`  --  it's an object in-and-of itself.  **in addition**  you need to **check** for equality.  A single `=` **sets** equality.  You need a `==` to check for `thruthy` value, or `===` to check for `exact` value (including string type IE integer etc etc)

**IE**

```js
$(document).on('input', '#now', function() {
  if ($('#now').val() == 100) {
    alert('Now!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="now" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have removed `MouseUp`and kept it simple using`OnChange` event handler

```js
$(function() {
  $("#now").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "100") {
      alert('Now!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="now" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="1" class="slider">
```